# Celery 3 and Flask Integration

Tags: python, flask, celery

I'm trying to get a basic example of this up and running:

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/celery/

So the article suggest placing this in a tasks module:

```
from celery import Celery

def make_celery(app):
    celery = Celery(app.import_name, broker=app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'])
    celery.conf.update(app.config)
    TaskBase = celery.Task
    class ContextTask(TaskBase):
        abstract = True
        def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            with app.app_context():
                return TaskBase.__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    celery.Task = ContextTask
    return celery
```

and this flask app.

```
from flask import Flask

flask_app = Flask(__name__)
flask_app.config.update(
    CELERY_BROKER_URL='redis://localhost:6379',
    CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND='redis://localhost:6379'
)
celery = make_celery(flask_app)


@celery.task()
def add_together(a, b):
    return a + b
```

But so far it just doesn't make sense as to what goes where.

Could somebody please provide a simple Flask-Celery 3 working example.

Regards,

Carl

Comment: What errors are you getting when you try this setup?

Comment: OK so I found this https://github.com/thrisp/flask-celery-example. Things make more sense now.

Answer (score -2):

[Github Repo for Flask-Celery](https://github.com/ask/flask-celery/)

I quote the author

> FROM CELERY 3.0 THIS LIBRARY IS NO LONGER NECESSARY, INSTEAD YOU SHOULD USE THE STANDARD CELERY API

For this reason is not necessary the use of Flask-Celery, Celery is independent of Flask. Please use the Flask good patterns.

Comment: The original question makes no reference to the flask-celery library. He isn't using it. He is using the standard celery API.